Next.js: Block rendering of page component until async function returns (app router)
This may be a super-basic question, but I can't find the answer here or in the Next.js docs.
I have a server-side page component that looks like this:
const Home: React.FC = async () => {
  const searchData = await getSearchData();
  // getSearchData() will eventually fetch(), but for the moment it's just returning
  // some static data to simulate the fetch.

  return (
    <main>
      <SearchForm {...searchData} />
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;

What I want to happen is for the server to send the Home component down to the client after getSearchData() returns (which will be nearly instantaneous). Instead, I get an empty SearchForm rendered, then searchData gets populated, then SearchForm is re-rendered. So somehow it seems like Next is executing my return statement and sending the component down to the client before getSearchData() returns. What's going on here, and what are my options to adjust the behavior?
Thanks!

Add conditional for the component return.
const Home: React.FC = async () => {
  const searchData = await getSearchData();
  // getSearchData() will eventually fetch(), but for the moment it's just returning
  // some static data to simulate the fetch.

  return (
    <main>
     {searchData  ?  <SearchForm {...searchData} /> : null}
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;


Interestingly that had no effect. Even weirder: if I put a console.log() of the props for SearchForm at the top of SearchForm's implementation, SearchForm renders (empty) before that console.log() executes. Which seems like it ought to be impossible.

Are you wrapping this component inside a client component

No, I don't think so. page.tsx is the top-level page in the app, and neither it nor the corresponding layout.tsx contains a "use client". SearchForm is a client component.

I just made a little test app with just this stuff in it and it works as expected, so clearly I've got some other weird thing going on here.

Were you able to find the issue

I was! Turns out I was looking at entirely the wrong thing—what was actually going on was that using certain libraries from react-icons was blocking the UI for several seconds. That may be a dev-mode-only thing, not sure, but I pulled react-icons out of the codebase even so.
